# sbcl illegal function call

Tags: syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp

I decided reading SICP a little, just to see what it is all about (I am not MIT student, actually already almost done with studying, this is no homework, but the content might be homework for someone.). Since I have installed sbcl, I have to change syntax a little, compared to the book. However, I don't understand why my solution to exercise 1.3 is not working:

```
(defun square (x) (* x x))

(defun sum-of-squares (x y)
    (+ (square x) (square y)))

(defun sum-of-squares-two-max (x y z) (
    (cond
        ((eq (min x y z) x) (sum-of-squares y z))
        ((eq (min x y z) y) (sum-of-squares x z))
        (t (sum-of-squares x y))
    )))
```

To load this I run `sbcl --load exercise-1.3.lisp`. When I load it, I get the error:

```
; file: /home/xiaolong/development/LISP/SICP/exercise-1.3.lisp
; in: DEFUN SUM-OF-SQUARES-TWO-MAX
;     ((COND ((EQ (MIN X Y Z) X) (SUM-OF-SQUARES Y Z))
;            ((EQ (MIN X Y Z) Y) (SUM-OF-SQUARES X Z)) (T (SUM-OF-SQUARES X Y))))
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     (DEFUN SUM-OF-SQUARES-TWO-MAX (X Y Z)
;       ((COND ((EQ # X) (SUM-OF-SQUARES Y Z)) ((EQ # Y) (SUM-OF-SQUARES X Z))
;              (T (SUM-OF-SQUARES X Y)))))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable X is defined but never used.
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable Y is defined but never used.
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable Z is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
;   caught 3 STYLE-WARNING conditions
```

Multiple things I don't understand:

1. Why are some variables not used? I use all of them in the conditional ...
2. Why is a function call illegal? How can I compose functions if I cannot call a function from inside a function? (I probably can, but I am doing it wrong?)

When I comment out the third function, it loads without errors.

I checked the syntax for the conditional multiple times already, cannot find the mistake.

How can I correct this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002497/lisp-illegal-function-call ?

Comment: The standard warns agains using `eq` for comparing numbers and characters: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_eq.htm The operator `eql` should be used instead. When comparing numbers, `= `is common.

Comment: @StanislavKondratyev Thanks, didn't know that. Somehow I thought there was no `=` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the extra open paren.

```
(defun sum-of-squares-two-max (x y z)
    (cond
        ((eq (min x y z) x) (sum-of-squares y z))
        ((eq (min x y z) y) (sum-of-squares x z))
        (t (sum-of-squares x y))))
```

The issue is that, with the paren, the code will call whatever your `cond` will evaluate to (as with all first items within parens). Without the paren, it knows that the result of the function is whatever the `cond` evaluates to.

Also, a general warning: SICP uses scheme, so you'll see some small differences between the book and what common lisp macros force you into.

Comment: Is there something called "parenthesis blindness"? If so, I had it! Yes, I know about it using Scheme : ) I got the impression, that Common LISP is more relevant in software today and already looked up some web dev tutorials for it, just to try that out. Is my impression wrong?

Comment: @Zelphir Your impression about the lisps is likely correct, I was just warning you to preempt further confusion. Also, look into rainbow parens to make paren matching easier (most editors have some sort of plugin-based support for these).

Comment: "to evaluate to something callable". Sorry, but no. The first element in a list, within standard evaluation rules, is *not* evaluated. It must be either a name or a literal lambda.

Comment: @Zelphir If you use an editor that handles indentation for you, the blindness quickly goes away.   E.g., if you indent in emacs, it looks like http://paste.lisp.org/display/322554.  It's hard to miss the fact that everything is off so far to the right.

Comment: Both are lisps, but Scheme is a more academic language with Racket being an implementation that works for real life applications. It's easy to learn one if you know the other, just like two C syntax languages. I started with CL with the book Land of lisp.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor no offense but that code looks really awkward to me and does not help me to see stuff like I did wrong in the OP (How would it? How could I conclude the too many `()`?). A simple break in the line before something indented and a single tab instead of *loads* of spaces has better readability.
I'd never write some parameters in the function's name line and the rest below. It gives the code a quirky look, as if some parameters are more important. I'd start on a new line if there are really that many parameters and indent every parameter by one tab relative to the functions name.

Comment: @Zelphir That code is *supposed* to look awkward.  That was my point.  When it's indented according to the parentheses that are actually there, things are way too far to the right.  That would be the tip-off or clue that there is some mis-parenthesization.